# Who / what exactly is the mysterious voice that Elsa hears?

Tags: frozen-2

In [*Frozen 2* (2019)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4520988/), Elsa hears a voice, like in the "Into the Unknown" song. Who or what is the source of that voice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That mysterious voice is of Iduna's spirit. She had the ability to talk to spirits when she was alive, and her selfless act to save Agnarr was responsible for making Elsa the fifth spirit.

Comment: I am doubtful about this answer but can't delete now. WIll dig more later

Comment: You need a citation for Iduna speaking to the spirits.  I don't remember that at all.

Comment: For now I accept it since I thought something like that too, but since I've only watched it once, and too engrossed in the story and graphics, I kind of forgot that detail and it's bothering my curiosity now.

Comment: It is Iduna, Disney confirms it, or maybe I'm too late too, https://screenrant.com/frozen-2-disney-elsa-voice-mother-iduna-confirmed/

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not from *Frozen*, but I think the answer works anyway:

"But the call isn't out there at all, it's inside me"

Or, the answer is "whoever gave her magic so she could be the bridge between humans and the magic nature spirits and heal the rift between Arendelle and the Northuldrans".